# URL: fetch Last Modified only (without content)

Tags: java, httpconnection

Is there a way to fetch just `Last Modified` header by using a `HttpConnection`?

When I use this code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
long lastModified = httpCon.getLastModified();
```

In the log files of the webserver I see:

```
a.b.c.d - - [26/Dec/2015:10:25:50 +0100] "GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

If I understand it correct, the `GET` request fetches the whole content as well. Is there a possibility to perform `HEAD` request to retrieve the headers only?

Comment: That comes from the response, which you can view using the following tut: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTTP method, see [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)):

> Set the method for the URL request, one of:
>
> - GET
> - POST
> - HEAD
> - OPTIONS
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - TRACE
>
> are legal, subject to protocol restrictions. The default method is GET.

Example:

```
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
long lastModified = httpUrlConnection.getLastModified();
```